# Golang and Cognito _ Invalid lambda function output

Tags: go, amazon-cognito

I have the code

```
func EjecutoLambda(event events.CognitoEventUserPoolsPostAuthentication) (events.CognitoEventUserPoolsPostAuthentication, error) {

    awsgo.InicializoAWS()

    if !validoParametros() {
        fmt.Println("Error en los parámetros. debe enviar 'SecretName'")
        err := errors.New("error en los parametros debe enviar secretname")
        return event, err
    }

    var datos models.SignUp

    for row, att := range event.Request.UserAttributes {
        switch row {
        case "email":
            datos.UserEmail = att
            fmt.Println("Email = " + datos.UserEmail)
        case "sub":
            datos.UserUUID = att
            fmt.Println("Sub = " + datos.UserUUID)
        }
    }

    err := bd.ReadSecret()
    if err != nil {
        return event, err
    }

    return event, bd.SignUp(datos)
}
```

But I receive the message
**Invalid lambda function output**

All the code works fine... the data is INSERTED into the database.

But when the lambda need to finish, I receive this error from cognito trigger

What's wrong ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Was my Mistake.

Using PostAuthentication, when the trigger is PostConfirmation